# add delay on onChange event in ionRangeSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, delay, ion-range-slider

I am using a ionRangeSlider for price range:

HTML

```
<input class="range-slider" id="price_range">
```

JS

```
        $("#price_range").ionRangeSlider({
            min: 0,
            max: 10000,
            type: "double",
            grid: false,
            step: 500,
            force_edges: true,
            decorate_both: false,
            prettify_enabled: true,
            onChange: function (data) {
                $('#loading').show();
                window.location.replace("@Url");
            },
        });
```

I want to add a delay of 2 seconds on `onChange` before redirecting to the url.

I have looked into the documentation but I can't find how to add a delay to the  `onChange` event.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this -

```
<body>
    <select id="select">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        var wto;
        $('#select').change(function() {
          wto = setTimeout(function() {
            // write your code here
            console.log('something changed');
          }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This change gets triggered whenever a new value is selected from the drop-down, but the alert will come after 2 seconds only.

Try this and let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Select object does not help me in my case. I need a slide ranger

Comment: try thi,setTimeout(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
    window.location.replace("@Url");
   }, 2000);

Comment: If I apply this and someone slides the ranger multiple times, there will be multiple calls to the same URL with 2 seconds difference between them. What i need is that these instructions in 'onChange' won't be triggered until 2 seconds after sliding the range-slider